# How to setup IDEA 13.1.2 to work with Gradle completely offline

Tags: android, intellij-idea, gradle

I need to start using Intellij IDEA 13.1.2 for my Android development, but I have to do so in a completely offline environment. I need to learn how to setup Gradle to work in such a scenario.

I understand i need to download the gradle-1.x-zip file but thats about it, im looking for a complete guide on how to setup the Gradle system so that I can create a New project and develop without any attempts to connect anywhere.

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 1):

IntelliJ IDEA now supports using Gradle in offline mode:

[image]

You should be able to enable Offline mode without any special configuration. Once you have the resources required to build your project, they will be cached in the Service Directory Path.

Comment: the problem is it fails to build from the start, it still tries to go online to do initial build, and gives the "unknown host services gradle host", my situation is that i dont have connection at all times, something else need to be done?